# Seeeduino V3.0 (Atmega 328P) and Rotary Angle Sensor Mystery Message

Tags: sensors, atmega328

I am attempting to do a simple example with the Rotary Angle Sensor.

**Here is my development environment:**

- [Visual Studio 2013 Premium](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-premium-with-msdn-vs.aspx)
- [Arduino Debug Tool](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Arduino-Debug-In-Visual-Studio.aspx)

[image: Visual Studio Solution and Projects]

**Board setup (Simple as can be single analog input):**
[image: Seeeduino V3 Setup]

**Code:**

```
const int ROTARYSENSOR = A0; 

void setup()
{
    Serial.println("Setup Start...");
    Serial.begin(9600); //Set the serial communication frequency at 9600 bits per second

    pinMode(ROTARYSENSOR, INPUT);

    Serial.println("Setup End!");
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Loop Start...");

    int value = analogRead(ROTARYSENSOR);
    Serial.println(value); //display on serial monitor
    delay(1000); //wait 1000ms before printing next value

    Serial.println("Loop End!");
}
```

**Issue:**

I have a single solution with multiple projects as my sensor playground. All other projects I have so far work flawlessly no issues.  Although with this project (RotaryAngleSensor) I am getting a strange message.

I am not seeing any of the Serial.println() messages. What is printed to the screen after a good 30 seconds is ***S?***

Does anyone know what could be returning this S? to the standard output?

Comment: Did you not post all your code? The `setup()` function is only called once, at the very start of the program running. It's possible you're just missing them.

Comment: Also, to be precise, your "rotary angle sensor" is **actually** called a *potentiometer*.

Comment: Yeah I lost some code somehow, when I was editing. I will update it. Also yeah I know what it's called, I was just using the name that was on the container box. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you try to generate serial output **before** you initiate Serial.  This could have odd results beyond just making that message fail.

```
Serial.println("Setup Start...");
Serial.begin(9600);
```

Should be

```
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Setup Start...");
```

And of course your posted code never reads the sensor...

Comment: It does, I must have lost the loop method when I reedited my question. Thanks.

Comment: So I flipped it around like suggested still didn't work. But when I remove the Serial.begin(9600); all together it works just fine, but just starts at 0. 

Suggestions?